# Error including socket libraries in C

Tags: c

I have found loads of guides to aid my process in socket programming, however i am **very** new to C and when I try to execute the program, it has errors with

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
```

Why is this? I am using Eclipse to do this. it wont compile and says "errors exist in this project, do you wish to carry on"

And highlights these two lines, its obvious it doesnt have those files to include.. no idea how to sort them out..

guide: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/clientserver.html#datagram

EDIT: coding it on a wnidows box, but will have to work/run on windows boxes and different flavours of linux

Comment: What platform? Also, includes are typically like this: `#include <sys/socket.h>`

Comment: Are you using a # in front of the word include?

Comment: Downvotes are a bit harsh here I think.

Comment: http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm

is the tutorial

Comment: The question is, are you using a Unix-y system like Linux or Mac OSX, or are you using Windows?

Comment: @birryree i am coding it on a windows machine but the program will need to work with windows and different flavours of linux

Answer (score 2):

You need to include either "" or <> around the include files. You also need a # symbol.

For example:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>    
#include <netinet/in.h>
```

Comment: yeah they are like that - i was having a mare wit hthe editor

Comment: Click the 'edit' button below your question and make the changes. Also it would be worth adding what the error messages are so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Those header files are available on unixy operating systems like FreeBSD, Mac OSX, and linux. Since you are using windows right now, you will have to use winsock, which is Windows' own implementation of the BSD sockets API and has different headers and some slightly different function names.

This is detailed in one section of Beej's guide: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#windows

He also mentions installing cygwin which would allow you to use the headers you are using right now, but I'm not sure if that would be an option for you.